# Consulta por el view model

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas amigos del foro, he aquí de nuevo molestando soy novato en las lides de android studio y termine de realizar mi primer app y leyendo e investigando es recomendable utilizar en los fragment el View Model, por lo cual realice los siguientes pasos, punto 1 realizar las dependencia en el buidgardle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.9'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.7.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.7.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

por el paso 2 realice la creación de la clase java, del view model:

```
package com.example.gestion.archivos;

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel;

public class primermodel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<String> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setData(String newData) {
    data.setValue(newData);
}

public LiveData<String> getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

por el paso 3 me dirijo al primer fragment y realizo esta secuencia:

```
public class ingreso1 extends Fragment {

EditText txtpresupuesto,txtnombre4,txtrut4,txtfecha1,txtnombre5,txtsiniestro,txtnombre6,txtfono4,txttercero,
        txtfonotercero,txtmarca2,txtmodelo1,txtano,txtpatente,txtchasis,a,b,c,d,e,f,j,txtusuario9,txtid;
Button btn_buscar,btn_limpiar,btn_salir;
Spinner sppatente;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;
private primermodel primero;
```

posteriormente realizo esto:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ingreso1, container, false);
    primero = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(primermodel.class);
    txtpresupuesto = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpresupuesto);
```

resto del código
y llegando a este punto me dan estos errores:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ViewModelProvider'
```

que corresponde al import:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
```

y el mismo error para la línea:

```
primero = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(primermodel.class);
```

a que se debe este problema, si estuve leyendo de los pasos a seguir y me da este error, favor de ayudarme y como poder solucionarlo, si necesitan algo más me lo hacen saber y desde ya muchas gracias.